# Удалить дубликаты элементов из массива

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Суть задания в том, что необходимо удалить серии повторяющихся элементов в массиве, оставив один элемент из серии. Я тут написал кой-чего, однако оно не работает должным образом. Возможно, вся проблема в [i + 1], но я без понятия как можно сделать по другому. Буду благодарен за любую помощь

```
int main() {
    setlocale(0, "");
    srand(time(0));

    const int size = 10;
    int count = 0;
    int arr[size] = { 1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,5 };

    cout << "Исходный массив: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
        if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1]) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout << "\nМассив без серий одинаковых подряд идущих элементов: ";
    int* arr2 = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1]) {
            arr2[i] = arr[i];
        }
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cout << arr2[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Забавно - вот буквально 10 минут, как [писал такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219088/195342) :)

Но там хоть C - а вам с C++ кто мешает использовать `unique`? Ну, нет так нет...

```
const int size = 10;
int a[size] = { 1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,5 };

int j = 0, r = 0;
while(++j < size)
    if (a[r] != a[j] && ++r != j)
        a[r] = a[j];

// В r - количество разных элементов

for(int i = 0; i <= r; ++i) cout << a[i] << " "; cout << "\n";
```